# Why so many capacitors in design?

Tags: power, capacitor, schematics, power-line-communication

I was looking the schematic for programming a standalone AVR chip.

[image]

I am curious why we need so many capacitors.

As far as i know, i know we need one capacitor on the power supply. I don't remember the name of this capacitor, but it supposedly filters the line.

So why are there extra capacitors?
Why is there a capacitor on the GROUND?

And why are there are two capacitors in the XTAL? And why two?

Comment: There are 4 capacitors in the circuit you linked i.e. that's hardly any at all. Have you done any background research on this at all?

Comment: I really dont understand your attitude. What is the problem in me asking a practical question? Were you born knowing this stuff? Should i just accept my ignorance and never learn? Should i ask your permission (or anyones) in knowledge?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The crystal capacitors are called "load" capacitors, and are **required** as part of the oscillator circuit.  The value of them depends on the specifications of the crystal being used.

The 100nF capacitors on the Vcc and AVcc pins are called "decoupling" capacitors, and one is **required** on every power pin.  They keep the power stable - without them the chip will crash.  They are the bare minimum you can get away with.  It is advised to have better decoupling on the AVcc pin, as well as proper ground plane separation for the analog portions.

I see no cacpacitor on ground...?

There are generally 4 classifications of capacitors in a circuit:

- **Filter capacitors**

These smooth and filter power supplies, removing ripple current, etc.

- **Reservoir capacitors**

These act as a short term low impedance storage of current for powering components that need it.  You should have one per roughly 3 or 4 chips depending on what the chips are.

- **Decoupling capacitors**

These are required on every power pin of every chip.  Some chips or power pins require more decoupling than others - the datasheet tells you if it needs anything out of the ordinary

- **Application specific capacitors**

These are all the other capacitors.  Capacitors that are used as part of some specific circuit, such as an oscillator, debouncing circuit, or whatever - they could be absolutely anything depending on the circuit that is being designed.